# PHP If Else load

Tags: php, if-statement, load

How does the load work with PHP If Else.

When a visitor loads the webpage will all code be loaded or will all code within the condition be ignored and not loaded if the condition isnt meet?

I am building a landing page with a countdown timer but it is only running when there is a discount.
I dont want it to load in the background on days where there is no need for it.

Comment: All code is ___loaded___ (unless you have includes inside if/else blocks); ___execution___ of code determines which route it follows on if/else

Answer (score 1):

The code is loaded into memory, but that is not really a problem. The PHP interpreter determines what code it actually needs to run at execution time. So if a 'if' condition isn't met, it will not run that bit of code.

Now, since PHP is serverside it will execute there and the client just gets the results. So, if you put the HTML for the countdown in a if statement that determines if there is a discount it will only send the countdown HTML as a response to the browser of the user if there actually is a discount.

Comment: Will it still load the scripts?
It will not execute the code but will it still load javascripts files even if they are in the condition and the condition is not meet?

Comment: the server does not load js, the browser does

Answer (score 0):

The code is loaded into memory if that is what your asking, but it is not siginificant.

If the condition isn't met, then the code will not execute at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body>
//this will show when the body loads 
<button type="submit">submit</button>
<?php
if(condition):
  //if condition is satisfied the control flow will execute inside the block           
  //and show the  below button
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
 else:
//this part will be executed/shown whether its php or html js.
?>
<?php endif ?>
 </body>
```